# Collective noun "police" — singular or plural?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, collective-nouns

A newspaper ran this headline today:

> Police *crack* down on IAC protesters.

Isn't the following more appropriate?

> Police *cracks* down on IAC protesters.

Comment: It takes a plural verb: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/police

Comment: Whyever would it take a singular verb?  It is not just one police who is doing the cracking down.  It’s the police force in general who are doing it.

Comment: ***Government** cracks down on IAC protesters*. As a Brit, I don' mind that "newspaper headline" using singular *or* plural verb with *government*. But *police* can only be plural to me. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: To me too. I suppose it's because the police are only ever perceived as police men and women and not as an abstract whole.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  This isn’t just a UK think.  *“The police”* will always be plural in North America, too.  I do not know why.  It just doesn’t work as a singular.

Comment: @Barrie,tchrist: I think Brits are more relaxed about plurality of many similar "group" words  - *the family, government, company, etc.* can be singular or plural, depending on context or the speaker's personal preference. But we'd never treat *police* as singular, even in contexts where it's clear we're referring to them as a collective unit (*Police have asked for extra funding during the Olympics*, for example). Strange.

Comment: @tchrist, the notion that  *“The police” will always be plural in North America* seems willfully perverse.  In the long run, North America will cease to exist, due to ordinary geological processes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers On the TV show "The Wire", police is repeatedly used in singular form to refer to police officers. For example, "he/she is a good police". Could you comment on how widespread this use is?

Comment: @painfulenglish: I'm not familiar with that usage (*The Wire* is an American show), so it sounds decidedly "odd" to me. But possibly in the minds of those who use it, it's a gender-neutral alternative to *policeman/policewomen*, in which case it has no bearing on the *Police cracks down on IAC protesters* suggestion above. Don't forget that TV shows are not above making up non-standard usages that are easily understood, purely to give the impression they're giving you a "glimpse behind the scenes" (even a *cop* can't be sure they don't use the term in other police forces).

Answer (score 0):

[According to ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/police):

> Definition of police
>
> *noun*
>
> [**treated as plural**] (usually **the police**)
>
> the civil force of a state, responsible for the prevention and detection of crime and the maintenance of public order:
>
> *local people have lost faith in the police*

Unlike (FF's) [government](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/government) which can be *treated as singular or plural*, *police* is *treated as plural*.