# Why is "police" referred to using the singular pronoun "it" in this sentence?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, personal-pronouns, collective-nouns, pronominal-agreement

With reference to this question [Collective noun "police" — singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79654/collective-noun-police-singular-or-plural) and as per my understanding *police* is always plural. But I got shocked after seeing *police* used as a singular noun in [this article](http://www.hindustantimes.com/News-Feed/Chunk-HT-UI-IndiaSectionPage-DelhiGangrape/Delhi-gangrape-Draft-chargesheet-finalised-police-to-cite-30-witnesses/Article1-983139.aspx):

> Two days after the death of the 23-year-old gangrape victim, Delhi Police on Monday said it has finalised around 1,000-page chargesheet in connection with the incident and plans to submit it in court on Thursday.

I can't figure out why they have used *police* as singular. It's one of the prominent newspapers in India. I doubt myself about its usage. Could anyone elucidate it further?

Comment: I took a quick look at the article you cite, but don't see *police* used singularly.  Can you edit to add the specific sentence you have questions about?

Comment: @Jim How to cite specific sentence?

Comment: @Sudhir- use a *greater-than* sign at the beginning of a line and then cut the words from the article and paste them in after it.

Comment: In the highlighted section of your question *police* is not being used as singular.

Comment: @spiceokooko  "Delhi Police ... said **it** has finalised ... But elsewhere in the article a sentence begins "Police have slapped ... ".  Both exhibit another nonSE usage, omission of the usual definite article.

Comment: This time OP seems to have accurately "cut&pasted" the original text. But because it includes the manifestly ungrammatical *it has finalised around 1,000-page chargesheet* as cited here (plus several other errors in the full text of the article), I'm voting to close as Too Localised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Singular *the police* seems to be very common in Indian English journalism.

Googling “the police have” and “the police has” with “site:indiatimes.com” yields claims of 1,430,000 hits for the plural and 525,000 hits for the singular—and on a quick “eyeball” survey the singular hits appear to be only about 5% or 10% false positives like “trust in the police has been shaken”.  “site:hindustantimes.com” yields 246,000 for the plural and 32,000 for the singular, and  “site:tribuneindia.com” yields a 7:1 preponderance of singular uses: 176,000 hits against23,000 hits on the plural.

Comment: @ StoneyB: So its common in Indian English journalism that police is used as singular more than that of plural?

Comment: @Sudhir  Well, as you see, what I present is just a glance, not a detailed survey. The Times of India prefers the plural by about 3:1, Hindustan Times prefers the plural by 8:1; but The Tribune prefers the singular by 7:1. It looks to me like in Indian English you get to choose which you prefer. See also my Comment beneath your question.

Comment: It may be common there, but that it is hardly Standard English, is it now?

Comment: @tchrist It is not now; but it may become so. There's certainly nothing in the grammar to forbid it.

Comment: There may be slightly more to it: The Metropolitan Police (of London) is generally singular but it's never without its definite article. One would write "The Met uses sirens a lot; Sussex Police don't do that."

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/collectivenoun.htm) gives a good reasoning on why collective nouns are used in singular and plural ways.

The police act as a single unit in the news report, so their actions are as a single unit. If the police were acting individually, then they would be referred to in the plural

Comment: "If the police were doing multiple things, then they would be referred to in the plural." What? I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @KitFox, changed explanation, to try to make it clearer.

Comment: But there are exceptions to the availability of both forms of agreement; 'police' certainly providing one in 'BrE' and probably 'AmE'. 'Manchester police has said it is investigating ...' would never be used.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other reasons presented, the term *Delhi Police* is a proper noun that is essentially a shortening of *the Delhi Police Department*, which normally would be spoken of in the singular.

Similarly, you would say "Customs has cleared my package for export."  Even though *Customs* is clearly a plural word, it is functioning as a short form of *the Customs Department*.